# Is there a way to persist Chocolatey package parameters so that they are silently reused on upgrade?

Tags: chocolatey

E.g. is it possible to set the `/NoSetAsDefault` parameter for the [PDFXchangeEditor](https://chocolatey.org/packages/PDFXchangeEditor) package so that it is used on `install` and each `upgrade`, including `upgrade all`?

Comment: So far the best solution I've found is to create an upgrade script that upgrades packages with specific parameters prior to updating all the rest:
`choco upgrade pdfxchangeeditor -params '"/NoSetAsDefault"' -y && choco upgrade all -y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to at least [Chocolatey v0.10.4](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and turn on the feature that does this for you automatically.

`choco feature enable -n useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades`

To better understand all of the considerations, please [read over issue #797](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/797).

**Note:** this feature is in preview currently to work out any unforeseen issues, but it will be turned on automatically in a future release.

You may also wish to subscribe to the [chocolatey-announce group](https://groups.google.com/group/chocolatey-announce) for release announcements in the Chocolatey ecosystem so you continue to be aware of new features and fixes.